# Keyboard Layout suddenly grayed out/disabled

Tags: keyboard, macos

I have been using a keyboard layout `usd2.keylayout` for 4 months on this laptop. After rebooting this last time (after many many other reboots..) it is grayed out.

Why might this be?  I am on el capitan

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
     $ll ~/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/
    total 80
    -rwxrwxrwx@  1 boescst  USWIN\Domain Users  37414 Nov 15  2015 usd2.keylayout
    drwx------+  3 boescst  USWIN\Domain Users    102 Nov 29 15:53 .
    drwx------@ 58 boescst  USWIN\Domain Users   1972 Mar 21 20:40 ..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here's a hack that has worked: I simply *re-added* the *same* keyboard layout. It now shows up twice .. but at least one of them is *enabled*.  I will go and delete the other (corrupted??) one now..

[image]

And deleting the previous (same file) one did clean it up.  That was .. *weird* ..

[image]